# bson@0.1.1 install: `node install.js`

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to install mongodb. I used the command >npm install mongodb<, but it gives the following response:

```
npm ERR! bson@0.1.1 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node install.js"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bson@0.1.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bson package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls bson
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mongodb"
npm ERR! cwd D:\GitHub
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.36
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message bson@0.1.1 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! message `cmd "/c" "node install.js"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\GitHub\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: I just installed it (Windows XP, node 0.8.5, npm 1.1.46) and it worked. Try upgrading to a later version of node (it's probably the newer version of npm that you need, but there were some changes to node itself that affected Windows versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that node is not in your path and I believe that npm shells out so if it's not in PATH it won't be able to find it. Therefore, in your case, add `C:\Program Files\nodejs` to your Windows "PATH" environment variable.